# I'm using a mongodb with a custom folder for saving data but that data is not synced with github because the files doesnt change

Tags: file, github, mongodb

I use github to version my files and I would like to version my database too, in this case is only for testing purposes.

But the database files created by mongodb are not changed, the files change data is weeks ago :s therefore the github has old data..

I can't really understand why if I'm changing some data in the database the mongodb doesn't save to a file... or at least the file must have changed somehow..

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB [preallocates datafiles](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-DatafilePreallocation) , which then get gradually filled. Perhaps that is why changes are not properly picked up.

As an aside, of all the possible ways of versioning a MongoDB database, I'm not sure that keeping the datadir itself in a Git repository is the best way to go.

Alternatives: running `mongodump` will result in a `BSON`-dump of your database or collection, while running `mongoexport` will result in a `JSON` or `CSV`. Both can be read back in with `mongorestore` and `mongoimport`, see [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools).

These dumps can then be versioned using you favourite tool. Personally, when using Git, I would version the JSON dump, e.g.

```
mongoexport --db mydatabase --collection mycollection > mycollection.json
```

will result in a JSON file, containing the contents of the chosen collection (you can dump the entire database if you want).

Something extra, if you append `--csv` and `--fields fieldname1,fieldname2`, you can dump a nice CSV-file, to read in with another program.

Comment: may you explain with an example, as I'm kind of new to mongoDb. Thanks